# How to filter, in real-time, a quasi periodic signal

Tags: filters, real-time

I have a signal affected by a rather complex quasi-periodic noise.

I must filter this signal in real-time to remove this noise.

The noise is not really "high frequency" and its main frequency vary slowly (several orders of magnitude compared to its period) but they are some phase discontinuities.

So I'm looking for a method to cancel this noise, ie. to find the envelope or quasi-DC offset of the signal. A simple moving average may introduce an important lag - so I suppose it might be possible to exploit the noise frequency stability to design a better filter.

Could I take the noise profile over a small previous period in order to attempt to filter it out (cancel fft bins or other methods?). Maybe you have other ideas?

[Edit]

A delay of one noise period could be acceptable, but the lower the better, of course.

Here is an exemple of signal :
[image]

[Edit 2]

Currently, I proceeded as follows: I estimate the period of the oscillations (I know that it varies slowly), I build a low-pass filter with this cut-off frequency. Finally I recalculate the frequency when the signal-to-noise ratio becomes too high. I get something like this, but I think we can do better (it lags).
[image]

Comment: Hm, I don't fully understand your noise model: Is it right to say it's a single tone that has phase jumps at irregular points in time? Also, you seem to be worry about delay of filters, but forgo to actually define a delay that's OK. If delay matters, you'll have to do that – everything in this world has some delay, and we can't guess from your question how much is OK.

Comment: A brief plot of what you are dealing with would help a lot too.

Comment: looks like you need a comb filter with notches at integer multiples of a given fundamental.  tuning the comb filter is going to be an issue of pitch detection.

Comment: OK, would it also be possible to sort of sketch or somehow describe what would you expect your processed signal to look like ideally? Are you trying to get to a signal that is "flat" and only contains the "walk bounces" for example? Is that where you are trying to get to?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added an exemple of my current filter. @A_A I mostly need the "DC/flat" component of the signal, eliminating bounces.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson thank you. Do you have a pointer/article/exemple about this method ?I guess it may works well for a very steady signal, but in this signal there are some potentially problematic phase breaks/irregularities.

Comment: significant phase breaks are not consistent with *"periodic"*.